# Divs not centereing one inside the other

Tags: php, css, html

I am showing multiple items from a db using a while in PHP.

For the formatting, I have the following CSS:

```
.similarItemsFrame
{
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.similarItems { 
    float: left;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin: 3px;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 1px;
 }

.similarImage {
     border: 3px solid white;
         margin: 0px auto;
     float: left;
 }
```

And the code to display is as follow:

```
echo "<div class='similarItemsFrame'>";
while ($row3 = $result3->fetch())
{
    echo "<div class='similarItems'>";
    echo "<a href='itemsDescr.php?itemId=".$row3[id_item]."'><img class='similarImage' src='http://www.tahara.es/images/{$row3[thumb1]}.jpg'></img>";
    echo "<div class='similarItemsText'>".$row3[name]."</a></div></div>";
}
```

The problem is that the IMGs do not come out centered. They come out 2 by 2 as I have it configured, but they are pushed to the left. The problem when I remove the `float: left` is that the items are totally misplaced.

Any advice?

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle, and I don't entirely know what look you are going for?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=centering+a+div+inside+a+div

Comment: I am trying to have everything centered

Comment: Wait, centered up and down div by div, or do you want the hole row to be centered left and right.

Comment: I want my items to be centered horizontally within my div.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display: inline-display;`, as appose to `float: left;`. More information here...
http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/